# Spring not able to find my JSP file even though everything is absolutely fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I got whitelabel error page while returing my jsp file because spring isn't able to find it. I referred everywhere did everything that was mentioned still wasn't able to resolve the error.
Things i tried:

1. Putting my jsp file in webapp folder inside WEB-INF
2. Added tomcat embed jasper in pom.xml
3. I've made sure the mapping is correct by adding @ResponseBody.

I tried to make a simple controller class to return a simple jsp file.

```
@Controller
public class sayHelloContainer {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

But no matter what i do i always get this error.

```
"Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [webapp/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]"
Resource not found
Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
```

I know it means it can't find my JSP file but according to me everything is fine.

Here's my `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

Here's my file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fu5C.png)

And here's my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Everything is not fine else it would have worked. `/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` is wrong. remove the `/webapp` part that is just a placeholder for the ending result. Also I would strongly recommend **not to use JSP** but something like Thymeleaf. JSP works with embedded tomcat but with limitations and only if you create a WAR file.

Comment: I didn't add webapp at first but it wasn't working then too so i added webapp hoping that it would work. Yea maybe i'll switch to Thymeleaf i've been stuck with this error for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Including the `webapp` directory in your path is not necessary.

Just set your properties to:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
```

Comment: Yea i didn't at first but it wasn't working that time too so i added webapp in hopes that it would work.

Comment: Whats the error message without webapp then?

Comment: Same stuff without the webapp part 
```
Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]
"FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp", parameters={}
"Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp]"
Resource not found

```